# Azure Functions in Java - using value from Service Bus trigger in Cosmos DB input binding

Tags: java, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function (in Java) that receives msgs via Service Bus, and I'd like to get a handle on a Cosmos DB record based on one of the properties in the incoming message, for example I receive a json message like so:
{ "id": "foo" }, and I want the Cosmos Input binding to give me the corresponding DB record.

There are plenty of examples on how to do this with an http trigger, but I can't figure out how to use a Service Bus trigger. I've tried variants like this:

```
    @FunctionName("ServiceBusListener")
    public void serviceBusListener(
        @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
            name = "message",
            topicName = "mytopic", 
            subscriptionName = "mysubscription", 
            connection = "AzureWebJobsServiceBus") String message,
        @CosmosDBInput(name = "name",
              databaseName = "MyDatabase",
              collectionName = "MyCollection",
              connectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString",
              id = "{message.id}") String item,

        final ExecutionContext context) {
            // do something with item
        }
```

Is there a way to do this?

[Edit] Forgot to mention that [C# supports doing this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-input?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#queue-trigger-look-up-id-from-json-c). My guess is Azure just doesn't support it with Java, as there are similar things supported in C# but not Java, like getting a handle on a DocumentClient or CosmosClient via an input binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with an Azure product manager, who confirmed that Java is lagging C# in Functions, and that the Cosmos input/output bindings aren't yet supported. Performance is lagging, too, e.g. HTTP triggers are all blocking. For now a static singleton instance of the Cosmos client is the recommended approach.

I'm going to stick with Java for my app b/c this is a simple application and we use Java for everything else, and I expect Functions Java support will eventually catch up. However if I didn't have all of those other considerations and this was a stand-alone project I'd probably go with C# at this point in time.